# Url doesn't allow underscore,slash(:\) in value field

Tags: c#, wcf-rest, uritemplate

I am developing a wcf rest service application,below is my uriTemplate.

> http://localhost:50782/PhotoManager.svc/UploadPhoto/?fileName={fileName}&description={description}

Below is my url that is from client side,

> http://localhost:50782/PhotoManager.svc/UploadPhoto/?fileName=001_003.jpg&description=D:\Image

But it shows error at underscore and slash.

Comment: Have you tried encodeURIComponent?

Comment: url decoding/encoding : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried with Uri.EscapeDataString(); but it is not work here.

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to the QueryString parameters not being escaped properly. From JavaScript you can use the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.

Comment: encoding is definitely necessary as the URI spec does not allow underscores anywhere in the URL.  Dashes are ok though.

Answer (score 0):

Check with following code in your System.ServiceModal section in Web.Config -

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="web">
    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
  </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```